# Customized select dropdown background image is not working in Firefox 30

Tags: html, html-select

Customized select dropdown background image is not working in lastest version of Firefox 30 but other browsers it's working fine(Chrome, Opera, IE11, Safari).

Below styles were working fine with Firefox 21 to 29 but in Firefox 30 its not working.

```
select {
  background: url(dropdown_arw.png) no-repeat right center;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 90px;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: "";
}
```

sample page - 
http://kvijayanand.in/jquery-plugin/test.html

Comment: ff 30 is officially out… ?:s

Comment: http://www.ghacks.net/2014/06/10/firefox-30-released-find-new/

Answer (score 0):

It may be that firefox and other browsers do not support a background images for select lists. I have tried to put a background for a select list in the past but it only works in some browsers. This is my best guess. You could try googling it if you already haven't.

Comment: there is no solution in your answer. its just a suggestion that you are trying to tell better you can put it in a comment section. Don't repeat the same again

Answer (score 0):

Known bug since 2011...

[Mozilla Official - BUGZILLA](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849)

I'm scared that you cannot simply do that via CSS. You should check something like [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/)